# Ability to click on a button as part of a background style WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, background, listbox

I have a ListBox that sometimes contains no items. If this ListBox contains no items, then a watermark and a notification in the form of a button with a tool tip will be displayed. I originally had the button at the bottom right corner of my screen. But it was requested I move the button to a more central location, specifically just below the watermark in the ListBox. I moved the button to the background of the ListBox initially but that did not work because I was unable to get the tool tip or press the button. 
My question is: Is there a way to have the button function properly on the background of the ListBox.

Style:

```
            <VisualBrush x:Key="WatermarkStyle" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Grid>
                        <Button
                            Margin="0,50,0,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Command="{Binding ReloadCommand}"
                            ToolTip="{Binding Path=NotificationTip}"
                            Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowNotification,
                                        Converter={StaticResource TrueToVisibleConverter}}" 
                            Style="{StaticResource StaticStyle}"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CanReload}">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=NotificationIcon}" Stretch="Uniform" Width="35"/>
                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="SEGOEWP" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Gray" Opacity="1" Text="{Binding BackgroundWatermark}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
```

ListBox:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox"
                 Grid.Row="2"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                 BorderThickness="1"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListView}"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDevice}"
                 SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WatermarkStyle}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Style>
```

Comment: too many questions so that I don't understand your actual problem. ***I'm not getting my tool tip, or the ability to click it. Is there a way to tell my ListBox to accept inputs through itself?*** The first problem is ***not getting my tool tip***, the next one is ***the ability to click it***, the most confusing is ***Is there a way to tell my ListBox to accept inputs through itself***. The first 2 problems seem to be related, even when the tooltip is shown, you cannot click or interact with that tooltip. Anyway please rephrase your exact problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just add a `Button` underneath the `ListBox`? Putting it into the `ListBox Background` is ridiculous... what would happen when the `ListBox` is full of items and covering the `Button`?

Comment: King King: Sorry, I guess I didn't do a very good job explaining. I will rephrase my question up top.  Sheridan: The button won't appear if the ListBox has any items. I originally had it in the bottom right corner, with a tool tip as to the reason the ListBox is empty. But I got a request to change it so its more central. I'll try to put it under the ListBox as you suggested.